# JavaScript getElementById with variables

Tags: javascript, html, list, variables, getelementbyid

I have seen similar questions, but none of them seem to fulfil my need. I need to get the disabled of a button, based on a list. [Here is my code:](http://jsfiddle.net/JkcB9/2/)

```
<button id="obj1" disabled>OBJ1</button>
<button id="obj2">OBJ2</button>
<button id="obj4" disabled>OBJ4</button>
<button id="obj5" disabled>OBJ5</button>
<button id="obj7">OBJ7</button>
<button id="obj8">OBJ8</button>

<script>
card_1_buttonList = new Array();
card_1_buttonList[0] = "1";
card_1_buttonList[1] = "2";
card_1_buttonList[2] = "4";

card_2_buttonList = new Array();
card_2_buttonList[0] = "5";
card_2_buttonList[1] = "7";
card_2_buttonList[2] = "8";

var CURRENTCARD = 2;
var BUTTONCOUNTER = 1;


var buttonDisabled = document.getElementById('obj' + card_CURRENTCARD_buttonList[BUTTONCOUNTER]).disabled;

alert(buttonDisabled);
</script>
```

How can I do this without modifying my existing arrays?

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JkcB9/2/)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: card_CURRENTCARD_buttonList is not defined`

Comment: @PsychHalf can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: you want to get id of disabled buttons??

Comment: @Joke_Sense10, no, I want to use the list of the buttons, to get the disabled of the buttons. It would come out as `var buttonDisabled = document.getElementById('obj' + card_2_buttonList[7]).disabled;`

Comment: Your card_2_buttonList array does not have an index of 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
card_1_buttonList = new Array();
card_1_buttonList[0] = "1";
card_1_buttonList[1] = "2";
card_1_buttonList[2] = "4";

card_2_buttonList = new Array();
card_2_buttonList[0] = "5";
card_2_buttonList[1] = "7";
card_2_buttonList[2] = "8";

var CURRENTCARD = 2;
var BUTTONCOUNTER = 2;

var buttonDisabled = document.getElementById('obj' + window['card_' + CURRENTCARD + '_buttonList'][BUTTONCOUNTER]).disabled;

alert(buttonDisabled);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Seawd/

Also, note that BUTTONCOUNTER is the array index, so 7 (as you had it) is not a valid value for it. You will need to do additional processing to get the index if you want the counter to be the value rather than the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Instead, you could create a two dimensional array with the following structure

```
var card_buttonList = [];

card_buttonList[0] = new Array();
card_buttonList[0][0] = "1";
card_buttonList[0][1] = "2";
card_buttonList[0][2] = "4";

card_buttonList[1] = new Array();
card_buttonList[1][0] = "5";
card_buttonList[1][1] = "7";
card_buttonList[1][2] = "8";
```

With this structure you'd be able to use indexes like this

```
var CURRENTCARD = 2;
var BUTTONCOUNTER = 7;

var buttonDisabled = document.getElementById('obj' + 
   card_buttonList[CURRENTCARD ][BUTTONCOUNTER]).disabled;
```

Comment: Since when is this valid javascript: `var card_buttonList = [][];`?

Comment: So I can't do it using my existing arrays?

Comment: @jfriend00: sorry, fixed that.

Comment: You can use your existing arrays if you'd like as shown below.

Comment: Instead of reformatting the original arrays, just add them to a master array: `var card_buttonList = []; card_buttonList.push(card_1_buttonList); card_buttonList.push(card_2_buttonList);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var CURRENTCARD = 2;
var BUTTONCOUNTER = 7;
var buttonDisabled = document.getElementById('obj' + card_CURRENTCARD_buttonList[BUTTONCOUNTER]).disabled;
alert(buttonDisabled);
```

The problem is in third line of this code. your name is wrong.
First try to make array name.

```
var cardArr = "card_" + CURRENTCARD + "_buttonList" ; // this will give you array name. like card_1_buttonList

var buttonDisabled = document.getElementById('obj' + window[cardArr]BUTTONCOUNTER]).disabled;
```

I think this will work.